# In the case of the two necessary roots of a quadratic function, are the two in a union relation or an intersection?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In some books, roots are shown to be $x = 4$ or $5$ and in some they appear as x = $4$ and $5$. Which one would be appropriate in the case of roots of quadratics or any higher degree of polynomials?

Thank you.

Comment: "If $x$ is a root, then $x=4$ or $x=5$" vs. "$4$ is a root, and $5$ is a root"

Answer (score 2):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $x=4$ and $x=5$ are the solutions of $x^2-9x+20=0$
- If $x^2-9x+20=0$ then $x=4$ or $x=5$

Comment: Thanks. I think I conflated the boolean/set use and colloquial use of the word 'and'.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a logic question, but rather about English grammar and making the statement understood.

If you are looking for a single root of the equation and have found two, your desired solution will be one or the other.

If you are looking for all the roots of the equation, these will be the first and the second.

It all depends on the context and the meaning you want to convey.

Comment: Right, thank you. I think I conflated the boolean/set use and colloquial use of the word 'and'.